# Unexpected pipe() behaviour

Tags: c, linux, pipe, fork, posix

I'm trying to make 2 processes to communicate over a pipe. I wait for the child to write a character in the pipe, and after that, the parent would read the character from the pipe and display it on the screen. The problem is that I successfully write the character in the pipe (I did a test to read immediately from it, and I saw that it was in the pipe), but when the parent reads from the pipe, there is nothing inside of it. I don't really understand why; everything seems fine.

```
int PID, canal[2];
if(-1 == (PID = fork()))
{
    perror("Error");
    return 0;
}
if(-1 == pipe(canal))
{
    perror("Error");
    return 0;
}
if(PID == 0)
{
    close(canal[0]);
    printf("Child\n");
    char buffer = 'C';
    if( 0 == write(canal[1], &buffer, sizeof(char)))
        printf("Didn't write anything\n");
    close(canal[1]);
}
else
{
    char readBuffer;
    wait(NULL);
    printf("Parent\n");
    close(canal[1]);
    if(read(canal[0], &readBuffer, sizeof(char)))
    {
        printf("I read: ");
        printf("%c\n", readBuffer);
    }
    close(canal[0]);
}
```

Comment: please, when asking a question about a run time problem (as this one is) post code that cleanly compiles (the posted code isn't even a whole program, and certainly does not compile)  post the actual input, post the expected output, post the actual output.

Comment: The `write()` function can return -1.  When that happens, an error occurred.  Should be checking for -1 and calling `perror()`  When the returned value is 0, should loop to try and output the rest of the data.  Please read the man page for `write()`, especially: "On  success,  the  number  of bytes written is returned (zero indicates
       nothing was written).  *It is not an error* if  this  number  is  smaller
       than the number of bytes requested; this may happen for example because
       the disk device was filled.  See also NOTES."

Comment: the child process should call `exit()`, not just run off the end of the 'if` code block (which means the child will execute anything after the end of the `else` code block which is probably not what you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that you call pipe after you call fork.  So the parent and child get different copies of the pipe.  Move the call to pipe before your call to fork.

Comment: Ah, I knew about this thing but I didn't notice my mistake. I should keep an eye on it at all times.